# Ownership mistake about duplicated unique_ptr items in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, stdvector, move-semantics

Considering the following code, how can I resolve the ownership problem I'm facing?

I need to handle this situation without making a copy of `Item` because I can't.

The `Item` and `ItemContainer` are part of an API which the user shouldn't concern about duplication, it means I need to silently add a pointer twice if user calls it twice for the same pointer.

I thought my deleter would resolve it, but it didn't.

I can't use an `unordered_set` for example, I should manage this situation as it is now.

ItemContainer.h:

```cpp
typedef std::unique_ptr<Item, std::function<void(Item *)>> ItemDeleter;
std::vector<ItemDeleter> items_;
```

ItemContainer.cpp:

```cpp
void ItemContainer::addItem(Item *item)
{
  ItemDeleter uniqPtrItem(item, [](Item *p) {
    if (p != nullptr) { 
      delete p; //it's crashing here, obviously
      p = nullptr;
    }
  });
  items_.push_back(std::move(uniqPtrTask));
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
int main() {
  Item *item = new Item();
  ItemContainer itemContainer;
  itemContainer.addItem(item);
  itemContainer.addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `std::shared_ptr` if you want multiple pointers to point to the same thing?

Comment: Good one! it was a requirement above of my scope.

Comment: Who creates the pointer? How will the user pass the same pointer on two different occasions? Who destroys the pointer?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `std::shared_ptr` (which is the obvious and most natural solution) then you can reference count your `Item`s.  Here is some simple demo code showing how to do that:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class RefCount
{
public:
    void Retain ()
    {
        ++refcount;
    }

    void Release ()
    {
        if (--refcount == 0)
            delete this;
    }

protected:
    virtual ~RefCount () {}

private:    
    int refcount = 1;
};

class Item : public RefCount
{
public:
    Item () { std::cout << "Item constructor\n"; }
private:
    ~Item () { std::cout << "Item destructor\n"; }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr <Item, void (*) (Item *)> ItemDeleter;

void addItem (std::vector <ItemDeleter> &items, Item *item)
{
    item->Retain ();
    ItemDeleter uniqPtrItem (item, [] (Item *p) { p->Release (); });
    items.push_back (std::move (uniqPtrItem));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector <ItemDeleter> items;
    Item *item = new Item;
    addItem (items, item);
    addItem (items, item);
    item->Release ();
}
```

Output:

```
Item constructor
Item destructor
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G5ZePChU0Eo6MLOM)

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints put in place by your situation, this is how I would resolve it.

If they're passing in raw pointers into the container, using `shared_ptr` won't work because you'd still have to check if the pointer was contained anywhere else in the container. The same applies for `unique_ptr` - you have to check if it appears anywhere else in the container.

There's no way around it: you have to check to see if the container already has the item. That being said, we can do that efficiently using an `unordered_map`. The map is going to keep track of how many times each item appears in the container, and when an item no longer appears in the container, it's safe to delete it.

```
template<class Item>
class ItemContainer {
    std::unordered_map<Item*, int> item_counts;
    std::vector<Item*> items; 
   public:
    ItemContainer() = default;
    ItemContainer(ItemContainer&&) = default;
    ItemContainer(ItemContainer const&) = default; 

    void addItem(Item* item) {
        item_counts[item] += 1;
        items.push_back(item); 
    }
    void removeTopItem() {
        // Get the top item and remove it from the vector
        auto item = items.back(); 
        items.pop_back(); 
        // Find the number of times the item appears in the vector
        auto iter = item_counts.find(item);
        auto& count = iter->second;

        if(count == 1) {
            // If it appeared only once, erase it from the map and delete the item
            item_counts.erase(iter); 
            delete item; 
        } else {
            // Otherwise, just update the count
            count -= 1;
        }
    }
    ~ItemContainer() {
        for(auto& count : item_counts) {
            auto item = count.first;
            delete item; 
        }
    }
};
```